# Remote desktop via web browser using C#/ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, web

I'm planning to create a VNC that can be view in browser. The inspiration for this code is Thinvnc but i would like to implement it using C# .NET . Is it possible to create such an application? what are the components that are going to use? thank you in advance ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, at least for VNC. Well, I'd say it would be better to go with the java on this one. You could take one of the open source projects and extend it's functionality so it is served from the web page.

if you really want to go with C# you'll need to use silverlight.

One thing is having a page and the other component that knows how to handle vnc. Using asp/html/... won't get you far - you need to use java/silverligh - C#/flash...

Best regards, 
 P.

Comment: Hello Sir. Thank you for your response :) I would like to ask if there's any open source that same with this project that need to be develop?

Comment: I don't understand the question sorry. If you're looking for the source code, you can get one here http://www.tightvnc.com/download-old.php for example.
VNC is a protocol and this is just one of the many implementations.

Comment: Sorry for confusion Sir . The main inspiration for this question is thinvnc [link](http://www.prweb.com/releases/html5/vnc/prweb4753884.htm) .. The user can view the other PC using Web browser